# Find an explicit formula for a square integer between $4n^3$ and $4n^3 + 4n^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, square-numbers

Given any positive integer $n>1$, it is fairly straightforward to prove that there exists at least one (and perhaps many) square integers lying strictly between $4n^3$ and $4n^3 + 4n^2$.  (Proof:  This is equivalent to the claim that there is an integer between $2n\sqrt{n}$ and $2n\sqrt{n+1}$, which is true because $2n\sqrt{n+1} - 2n\sqrt{n} > 1$.)  Does anybody see a way to find an explicit formula (in terms of $n$, preferably as the square of a polynomial) for such a square integer?

Comment: It is $4n^3+n^2$ or $4n^3+4n^2$? To obtain a formula just solve the inequality $4n^3\le m^2\le 4n^3+(4)n^2$.

Comment: What about $4*1^3=4$ and $4*1^3+4*1^2=8$. $5,6,7$ aren't square.

Comment: @NickGuerrero correct, I neglected to include the condition $n>1$.  That's fixed now.

Comment: @Masacroso  The original post omitted the coefficient on $n^2$, which I corrected.  But yes, my question is precisely *how* to solve that inequality.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense then. How about $\lfloor{\sqrt{4n^3+4n^2}}\rfloor$?

Comment: @NickGuerrero  Seems like cheating.  :)    I'd really like a polynomial in $n$, or an integer-valued rational function.

Comment: I don't think you can get such a polynomial.  As a function of $n$, this square grows like $n^3$.  The square of a polynomial in $n$ grows like $n$ to an even power.

Comment: Well, after doing some digging, I can say that OEIS doesn't have any sequence that matches these integers.

Comment: @MatthewConroy  I think you have distilled the essence of the question and explained why what I am looking for doesn't exist.  If you would like to post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose we have a polynomial $r$ such that $r(n)^2$ is a perfect square with $$4n^3 \le r(n)^2 \le 4n^3+4n^2$$ for all $n$.  Suppose $r(x)$ has degree $k$.  Then
$$
\frac{4n^3}{n^{2k}} \le \frac{r(n)^2}{n^{2k}} \le \frac{4n^3}{n^{2k}}+\frac{4n^2}{n^{2k}}.$$
Letting $n$ go to infinity, the middle expression approaches a non-zero constant, and we conclude that $2k\ge3$ and $2k\le3$, i.e., $k=\frac{3}{2}$. Since $k$ is an integer, this is a contradiction.  Hence, no such polynomial $r$ exists.

Comment: Moreover the same argument (with minor modifications) shows that $r(n)$ can't be a rational function, either.